# why my mac opens with do not disturb mode although I didn't schedule?

Tags: macos, notifications, do-not-disturb

I don't choose any option on about Do Not Disturb. I added ss to you can see my settings. But sometimes Do Not Disturb mode opens automatically. (MacOS 11.2 Big Sur, Macbook Air 2017)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the terminal
2. Type `killall NotificationCenter`

This fixed it for me. I've found the solution on [this reddit thread](https://old.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/kcvdn4/cannot_turn_off_the_do_not_disturb_on_big_sur_is/gj04n0t/?context=3).

Comment: thanks a lot. It works but I need to know what's the reason? is it a bug?

Comment: I don't know! I suspect a bug, but there's nothing concrete on that thread; I wasn't able to find more details either.

Comment: It doesn't look like this persists across the restarts though

Comment: I think apple support will give its reason to me. I will add here if I have fix way

Comment: @DrAchernar Has Apple Support response yet? This bug does happen at each restart and is quite annoying

Comment: sometimes i see this issue -still-, they can't find cause and havent idea :/ but i guess reason is my external monitor